# Send data from Django to another server

Tags: python, django

I have an already existing Django app. I would like to add a system that sends data from my Django application to another Python application hosted on another server, so that the Python application receives data from the Django App in json format, possibly.

So for example, i would need to create a view that every tot seconds sends the data from a DB table to this application, or when a form is hit, the data is sent to this external application.

How can i do this? Is there an example for this particular matter? I don't know what tools i'd need to use to create this system, i only know that i would need to use Celery to perform asynchronous tasks, but nothing else; should i use Webhooks maybe? Or Django channels?

Edit: adding some more context:
I have my Django client. Then i have one or two Python applications running on another server. On my Django client i have some forms. Once the form is submitted, the data is saved on the db, but i also want this data to be sent instantly to my Python applications. The Python applications should receive the data from Django in Json format and perform some tasks according to the values submitted by users. Then the application should send a response to Django.

Comment: Why not use `requests` and send the data from your application to other application?

Comment: Can you connect to both servers by ssh?

Comment: Do you want to work with two apps of your own to talk to the data? Both are in Python and one is in Django? Is this second using any framework? Still without all the information I think you could just make the databases communicate and use serializers within the applications to combine the data, maybe you would have greater speed and persistence of your data.

Comment: @EndersonMenezes i added some more context

Comment: I do something similar to what you do, I will try to explain to you. I am sorry for my english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Come on! I'll call your Django app here **"DjangoApp"** and your Python apps, in Flask or another framework by **"OtherApp"**.

First as you predicted you will need a framework that is capable of performin**g tasks, the new **Django 3.0** allows this, but **I haven't used** it yet ... I will pass on to you something that you are using and fully functional with Django 2.8 and Python 3.8**.

On your DjangoApp server you will need to structure the communication well with your Celery, let's leave the tasks to him. You can read [Celery Docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) and [this post](https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/), its very ok to make this architecture.

Regardless of how your form or Django App looks, when you want it to activate a task in celery, it is basically the function to transmit data but in the background.

```
from .tasks import send_data

...
form.save()
# Create a function within the form to get the data the way you want it
# or do it the way you want.
values = form.new_function_serializedata()
send_data.delay(values) # [CALL CELERY TASKS][1]
...
```

Read too [CALL CELERY TASKS](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html)

In all your other applications you will need to have a POST route to receive and serialize this data, do this with lightweight frameworks like [Pyramid](https://trypyramid.com/)

This way, every time a form is submitted, you will have this data sent to the server within the send_data function.

In my experience, but not knowing much about your problem I would use a similar architecture but using [Celery Beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'send_data': {
        'task': 'your_app.tasks.send_data',
        'schedule': crontab(), # CONFIGURE YOUR CRON
    },
}
```

Not only is the above code added, but it is something like that.

Within your models I would create one field for **sent**. And every 2 seconds, 10 seconds .. as long as I wish I would filter all objects with sent = false, and pass all objects for the send_data task.

I don't know if you got confused, that's a lot to explain. But I hope I can help and answer your questions.

Comment: This is a valid approach! But what if i use Django-channels? How would it change from using Celery?

Comment: I have never specifically used Channels, but you would have to check how is its structure .. is it an open project? Is there on github?

Comment: Yes, it is an open project, it's on github!

Comment: Post link and i will see the configs another day.

Comment: Just one more thing. I understand the whole Django part of your code; but how does my external python script receive the data? I mean, does it have to connect to a certain url?

Comment: You must use a super lightweight script to mount a POST route, so if somehow you need to have this other web server exposed.

I recommend Pyramid for punctual work.
[Link] (https://trypyramid.com/)

Comment: Another way would be for the external script not to receive data but to consume, then you would have to in your Django, leave a GET route of consumption open, and make your external script consume with requests. It depends on how you want your final architecture, and how your script and server limitations are.

Comment: Well, the most important feature of this system should be speed, so as soon as the django form is submitted, the data must be receveid by the external python script asap

Comment: Your response time using Pyramid and Python with Django to do this will depend almost solely on the connection between these two servers. I recommend seralising this data manually as well to speed up data processing.

Comment: See [This bench](https://voidfiles.github.io/python-serialization-benchmark/) and https://medium.com/@shmulikamar/python-serialization-benchmarks-8e5bb700530b

Comment: Do you know MessagePack?

Answer (score 5):

```
import requests
from django import http

def view(request):
    url = 'python.app.com'  # replace with other python app url or ip
    request_data = {'key': 'value'}  # replace with data to be sent to other app
    response = requests.post(url, json=request_data)
    response_data = response.json()  # data returned by other app
    return http.JsonResponse(response_data)
```

This is an example of a function based view that uses the requests library to hit an external service. The request lib takes care of encoding/decoding your data to/from json.

Comment: But don't you think using REST API calls will be quite slow. Can you suggest some other methods?

Comment: Why would it be slow? It's an application on the same box. You could use a direct db connection if that's an issue but the OP wanted json. One could also store the data in a queue and have a cron or task runner consume it, but OP's other python app needs to process the data and return something.

Comment: So basically, i would be sending the content as Json to the external Python application?

Comment: In your original post's edit you mentioned that you wanted to send json to the external Python app, so I'm not sure what you're asking in this comment. To answer, yes my answer sends the content as json to the external py app.

Comment: @Airith ok! But how would my external python app receive the data sent?

Comment: I assumed your external py app was listening for http requests and could parse the json it receives. I can't really answer without knowing anything about this external py app.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, webhook would be one of the options, but there are other options available too.

-> You can use Rest Apis to send data from one app to another. but In their case, you need to think about synchronization. That depends on your requirement, If you don't want data in synchronize manner then you may use RabbiMq or other async tools. Just push your rest API request in Rabbitmq and Rabbitmq will handle.